# Create neasted elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create div with div inside with jQuery.
At the beginning in html I have:

```
<section>
</section>
```

And after I would like to get:

```
<section>
    <div class="mate">
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

this is a script:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "{{addr}}",
            success: function(data) {
            for(i = 0; i < data['team'].length; i++) {
                $('<div/>',{
                    class:'mate',
                    /* Here is a problem */
                    text: "<div class='name'>"+data['team'][i]['name']+"</div>",
                    }).appendTo('section');
                }
            }});
```

Comment: Change `text` to `html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a string that I increment , like :

```
var stuff = "<div class='mate'>";

for(i = 0; i < data['team'].length; i++) {
    stuff += "<div> Content" + i + "</div>";
}

stuff += "</div>";

$('section').append(stuff);
```

You can even nest `for` loops to nest divs deeper :)